# Getting the System tick count with basic C++?

Tags: c++, time, android-ndk, porting

I essentially want to reconstruct the getTickCount() windows function so I can use it in basic C++ without any non standard libraries or even the STL. (So it complies with the libraries supplied with the Android NDK)

I have looked at

> clock()
>
> localtime
>
> time

But I'm still unsure whether it is possible to replicate the getTickCount windows function with the time library.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to do this or even if its possible?

An overview of what I want to do:

I want to be able to calculate how long an application has been "doing" a certain function.

So for example I want to be able to calculate how long the application has been trying to register with a server

I am trying to port it from windows to run on the linux based Android, here is the windows code:

---

```
int TimeoutTimer::GetSpentTime() const
{
if (m_On)
{
    if (m_Freq>1)
    {
        unsigned int now;
        QueryPerformanceCounter((int*)&now);
        return (int)((1000*(now-m_Start))/m_Freq);
    }
    else
    {
        return (GetTickCount()-(int)m_Start);
    }
}
return -1;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?  There may be ways to do it.  Perhaps take a step back and explain the general problem.

Comment: Good idea, I want to be able to calculate how long an application has been "doing" a certain function. So for example I want to be able to calculate how long the application has been trying to register with a server

Comment: In that case it is probably pretty trivial to find/create an object that can figure out elapsed time.  Are you looking for thread/scheduled time, or overall clock/wall time?

Comment: I am porting it from Windows where it uses the elapsed time of the system though, so I'm unsure if an object that simply checks a start and finish time will be sufficent. I have posted the windows platform code in my question which may expalin it better

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On Android NDK you can use the POSIX clock_gettime() call, which is part of libc.  This function is where various Android timer calls end up.

For example, java.lang.System.nanoTime() is implemented with:

```
struct timespec now;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
return (u8)now.tv_sec*1000000000LL + now.tv_nsec;
```

This example uses the monotonic clock, which is what you want when computing durations.  Unlike the wall clock (available through gettimeofday()), it won't skip forward or backward when the device's clock is changed by the network provider.

The Linux man page for clock_gettime() describes the other clocks that may be available, such as the per-thread elapsed CPU time.

Answer (score 9):

`clock()` works very similarly to Windows's `GetTickCount()`.  The units may be different.  `GetTickCount()` returns milliseconds.  `clock()` returns `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` ticks per second.  Both have a max that will rollover (for Windows, that's about 49.7 days).

`GetTickCount()` starts at zero when the OS starts.  From the docs, it looks like `clock()` starts when the process does.  Thus you can compare times between processes with `GetTickCount()`, but you probably can't do that with `clock()`.

If you're trying to compute how long something has been happening, within a single process, and you're not worried about rollover:

```
const clock_t start = clock();
// do stuff here
clock_t now = clock();
clock_t delta = now - start;
double seconds_elapsed = static_cast<double>(delta) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

**Clarification:** There seems to be uncertainty in whether `clock()` returns elapsed wall time or processor time.  The first several references I checked say wall time.  For example:

> [Returns the number of clock ticks elapsed since the program was launched.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/)

which admittedly is a little vague.  MSDN is more explicit:

> [The elapsed **wall-clock time** since the start of the process....](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30(v=vs.100).aspx)

User darron convinced me to dig deeper, so I found a draft copy of the C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:TC2), and it says:

> ... returns the implementation’s best approximation to the **processor time used** ...

I believe every implementation I've ever used gives wall-clock time (which I suppose is an approximation to the processor time used).

**Conclusion:**  If you're trying to time so code so you can benchmark various optimizations, then my answer is appropriate.  If you're trying to implement a timeout based on actual wall-clock time, then you have to check your local implementation of `clock()` or use another function that is documented to give elapsed wall-clock time.

**Update:**  With C++11, there is also the  portion of the standard library, which provides a variety of clocks and types to capture times and durations.  While standardized and widely available, it's not clear if the Android NDK fully supports  yet.

Comment: This is not true. clock() returns the time spent by the process, which is usually much smaller than the total system time.

Comment: @darron:  I didn't say clock() returns system time.  In fact, I pointed out that difference in the second paragraph.  The question asked for a way to time how long something takes using standard C++ libraries.  My answer explains how to do that.

Comment: Well, the first and last paragraph seem to ignore the existence of the second. The example code will give you time SPENT on the process itself, not wall clock time since 'start'. So, if you have a very light process running for days, it's clock might only be at 5 seconds. It's not similar to GetTickCount() at all, besides being loosely timing something. I know this is an old question/answer but people still find these things and try to use the info provided.

Comment: @darron:  OK, I see your point now.  Every implementation of `clock()` that I've used has returned wall-clock time, not processor time.  I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hmm... strange.  Every implementation I've used has been processor time. (ie: gives a value of 2 minutes delta after a few days of running a lightweight task)  I've found a couple references to VC++ doing wall clock time now (as your MSDN excerpt says).

Answer (score 3):

This is platform dependent so you just have to write a wrapper and implement the specifics for each platform.

Comment: On Android only the very basic C libraries are provided, what you see under c library here - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ , it has no additional platform specfic extras

Comment: The C library do have the time.h isn't that available? It might not give you great resolution of time, but should be enough for your needs. use clock() with the CLOCKS_PER_SEC to get elapsed time.

Comment: @daramarak clock() returns the process time, not the system time.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.  The C++ standard and, as consequence the standard library, know nothing about processors or 'ticks'.  This may or may not change in C++0x with the threading support but at least for now, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to a vblank interrupt function (or hblank) on the Android?  If so, increment a global, volatile var there for a timer.