# Equivalent of System.nanoTime() for NDK apps?

Tags: android, c++, time, android-ndk

My Android NDK C++ application receives touch events and uses the `AMotionEvent_getEventTime()` to get the time of a touch event. I need to compare that time to time values which I sample on my own during the app execution. The function [docs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___input.html#ga7e13fbf3cff0700b0b620284ebdd3a33) say it gives its time "in the java.lang.System.nanoTime() time base", so I need to have the equivalent of this call in my C++ code.
The best clue I got is `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` but is it really that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832097/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738669/

Answer (score 2):

Found the implementation of System.nanoTime:

https://github.com/android-ia/platform_libcore/blob/master/luni/src/main/native/java_lang_System.cpp

Comment: Yes, System.nanoTime() is implemented using CLOCK_MONOTONIC on Android.